# need spring security ntlm source code 2.04

Tags: java, spring-security

i cant find source code for spring security ntlm 2.04 ntlm.jar source code. any ideas where can i get this old release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's also in the Maven central repository:

http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-ntlm/2.0.4/spring-security-ntlm-2.0.4-sources.jar

So you can either download it from there or automatically add it your IDE if you're using Maven to generate your IDE files (e.g. using "mvn eclipse:eclipse").

And of course, since it's an Open Source project you can get it from the source repository:

```
svn checkout https://src.springsource.org/svn/spring-security/tags/spring-security-parent-2.0.4/
```

Answer (score 2):

It's in the zip file here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/springframework/files/spring-security/2.0.4/spring-security-2.0.4.zip/download (filename: spring-security-ntlm-2.0.4-sources.jar)